# Adjacent triangles in a Von Dyck group

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry, tiling

A [Von Dyck group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#Von_Dyck_groups) is a subgroup of the triangle group. For example $D(2,3,7)$ can be represented as the black triangles in

[image]

by picking an arbitrary black triangle as the identity element. Each triangle then corresponds to the isometry mapping the identity triangle to it.

The $D(l,m,n)$ is isometry group can be generated by two rotations, a rotation $x$ of $\frac {2 \pi} m$ radians (around the vertice of the identity triangle of angle with angle $\frac \pi m$) and the rotation $y$ of $\frac {2 \pi} y$ (around the vertice of the identity triangle of angle with angle $\frac \pi y$). Then the group can be repersented as

$\langle x,y | x^m = y^n = (xy)^l = 1 \rangle$

My question is, given an element of $D(l,m,n)$, represented by a string of $x$ and $y$, how can we tell if the triangles they represent share a vertice, and if so, which one? (I am particularly interested in the case $l=2$, but a general answer would be nice.)

I think it has something to do with conjugates, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your question does not make sense linguistically: "given an element, how can we tell if the triangles they represent...". Do you mean given two elements?

Comment: @DerekHolt Two elements; sorry for the typo.